# Inserting text and an image into the header

Tags: fancyhdr, includegraphics, header

How would you modify the current code so that I can insert a small image as part of the centred header in the highlighted spot?

Thank you!

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}     
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations,babel,patterns,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{center}
\end{center}
%
\newpage
\newgeometry{left=0.8in,right=0.8in,top=1.0in, bottom=0.8in}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\voffset = 0 cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\definecolor{Elite}{RGB}{80,129,188}
\newcommand{\mymk}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=south west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=2pt, minimum size=7mm, text height=2mm](char){\ensuremath{#1}} ;}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,fill=Elite!50,inner sep=3pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\chead{{\LARGE \textcolor{Elite}{MATHS TEST}}
%   \includegraphics{No_calculator.png}}
XX
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\cfoot{\LARGE\bf \textcolor{Elite}{\thepage}}
%--------------------------
\fontsize{14}{20}\selectfont
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=Elite,boxrule=1.3mm,colback=white,width=17cm,height=23.2cm,after=\hfill,segmentation style={draw=Elite,line width=3pt,solid}]
{\huge\bf \circled{1}}\quad QUESTION 1
\end{tcolorbox}
\newpage
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have it in your code already, but it is commented out: `\includegraphics{...}`.

Comment: When I run this code with the \include.. bit re-instated, the text gets wiped for some reason. This is why I am seeing some adivce.

Comment: You may need to downscale the graphics: `\includegraphics[height=2ex]{...}`

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right about having to downscale the image.

Comment: Please, don't use `\bf` in LaTeX. Two-letter font commands are obsolete by decades. More generally, you should clean up your preamble. You're loading things several times and sometimes in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a No calculator graphic file, but I made one from `\faCalculator` (`fontawesome5`) with the help of packages `bbding` and `stackengine`:
[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations,babel,patterns,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{fontawesome5, bbding, stackengine} 

\begin{document}
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{center}
\end{center}
%
\newpage
\newgeometry{left=0.8in,right=0.8in,top=1.0in, bottom=0.8in}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\voffset = 0 cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\definecolor{Elite}{RGB}{80,129,188}
\newcommand{\mymk}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=south west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=2pt, minimum size=7mm, text height=2mm](char){\ensuremath{#1}} ;}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,fill=Elite!50,inner sep=3pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\chead{{\LARGE \textcolor{Elite}{MATHS TEST\quad\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\textcolor{red}{\XSolidBrush}}{\scalebox{1.1}{\faCalculator}}}}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\cfoot{\LARGE\bf \textcolor{Elite}{\thepage}}
%--------------------------
\fontsize{14}{20}\selectfont
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=Elite,boxrule=1.3mm,colback=white,width=17cm,height=23.2cm,after=\hfill,segmentation style={draw=Elite,line width=3pt,solid}]
{\huge\bf \circled{1}}\quad QUESTION 1
\end{tcolorbox}
\newpage
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}

\end{document}
```